# SVG graphics not showing on my home page

Tags: svg

I have been using svg graphics as a css background in my website and cannot get them to show on my site. Is there an easy way to troubleshoot why this may be happening? I disabled all the css on my site bar the rule that drives the facebook icon css background? This however did not have an effect and the graphic was still hidden? When i replace the svg with a png graphic the icon shows fine.

The page in question is at:
http://sandpit.jonathanbeech.co.uk/

I used the same code on a test html page on my local machine and the svg graphic appeared perfectly. is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this issue? Is there something that is clashing with the svg capabilities of the browser within the code I have written?

Here is the html

```
<div>
<h3 class="cliptypeheadersmaller">Connect with me</h3>
<div class="svgicon"></div>
<ul>
<li class="facebook_main_col"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Linked In</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css.

```
/* @group svg icons */

.facebook_main_col {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(../images/facebook-square-icon.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.svgicon {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(../images/facebook-square-icon.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 82px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything on your page apart from markup. I do see none of the other png images load, do you have them stored locally or something ? My best guess is that the svg file isn't findable. Check if you can see it via the full url in the browser (as I can't see it, so assume thats the problem).

Comment: Thanks @Ian It looks like you were correct, the graphic now appears to load correctly.